# Uneven Spacing Using CSS Table Display

Tags: css, responsive-design, width

I have a navigation menu on a responsive site design that I want to fill the full width of the container, with each item evenly spaced. I'm using display:table and display:table-cell, but the spacing between the menu selections is uneven.

Any suggestions?

Here's the CSS code:

```
ul#top-nav {
  margin: 14px auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: table;
  text-align: center; }

ul#top-nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #959484;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 30px; 
}
```

And here's the result:

[image: Resulting Menu]

A few caveats:

1. The menu items are dynamic, so they can't be hardcoded to a specific width.
2. The relative positioning is there to accommodate the placement of the dropdown menus.
3. I've tried using floats, already.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

ty

Comment: You could play around with padding on the `li`s. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwBwgX

Comment: Are you looking for `table-layout: fixed;`

Comment: A combination of these led to the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use padding to separate out the elements

Check out the this demo http://jsfiddle.net/x9rzbm9p/4/

```
.table {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 30px; 
    border: 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This wound up doing the trick:

```
ul#top-nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #959484;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 30px; 
    padding: 0 1%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

It was a combination of each of the three comments/responses that led me there, so thank you so much.